# Memory leak in ImagePickerView in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am using the Scrollviewer to load images. I get the images from Media Library and save it into local folder.  If I select and add images more than 5, app get memory warning level2 app get crash.

This is code to get the Photos from database:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) GetPhotos:(int)folderId
{
    NSString *query =[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Photo WHERE FolderID = ?"] autorelease];
    
    FMDatabase *db = [self.dbUtils sharedDB];
    
    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:query, [NSNumber numberWithInt:folderId]];
    
    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    while([rs next]) {
        
        Photo *photo = [[Photo alloc] init];
        
        photo.PhotoID = [rs intForColumn:@"PhotoID"];
        photo.FolderID = [rs intForColumn:@"FolderID"];
        photo.PhotoName = [rs stringForColumn:@"PhotoName"];
        photo.UpdatedDate = [rs stringForColumn:@"UpdatedDate"];
        photo.ImageData = [rs dataForColumn:@"ImageData"];
        photo.Path = [rs stringForColumn:@"Path"];
        photo.isPrivacy = [rs boolForColumn:@"isPrivacy"];
        
        
        [results addObject:photo];
        [photo release];
        
    }
    
    [rs close];
    
    return results; 
    
}
```

Pick the images from Image picker view controller:

```
#pragma mark  UIImagePickerController delegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    
    PrivacyPixAppDelegate *appDelegate = [PrivacyPixAppDelegate appDelegate];
    
    dispatch_queue_t image_queue;
    image_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.gordonfontenot.app", NULL);
    
    dispatch_async(image_queue, ^{
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 
            
            NSString *fileDirectory =  [FileUtils documentsDirectoryPath];
            fileDirectory = [fileDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@/",self.FolderName];
            NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[appDelegate newUUID]];
            
            Photo *photo = [[Photo alloc] init];
            photo.PhotoName = fileName;
            photo.Path = fileDirectory;
            photo.FolderID = self.FolderID;
            photo.isPrivacy = FALSE;
            self.btnEdit.hidden = NO;
            
            
            fileDirectory = [fileDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",fileName];
            NSLog(@"FileName:%@",fileName);
            NSLog(@"Directory:%@",fileDirectory);
            
            NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage,5.0);
            [jpegData  writeToFile:fileDirectory atomically:NO];
            
            PhotoDAO *dao = [[appDelegate daos] sharedPhotoDAO];
            
            [dao AddPhoto:photo];
            [photo release]; 
            
            NSMutableArray *list = [dao GetPhotos:FolderID];
            self.listData = list;
            [list release];
            
            [self loadForm:self.listData];
            
            
        });
        
        
        
        
        
    });
    dispatch_release(image_queue);
        
        
}
```

This is method for load images into scrollviewer. This method only problem to memory leak

```
-(void)loadForm:(NSMutableArray*)list
{
    NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    
    if([list count] == 0)
        self.btnEdit.hidden = YES;
    else
        self.btnEdit.hidden = NO;
        
    for (int Count = 0; Count < [list count]  ; Count ++)
    {
        Photo *photo = [list objectAtIndex: Count];
        
        PhotoView *photoView = [[PhotoView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(ThumbnailSizeWidth * (Count % THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING * (Count % THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING,
                                                                                           ThumbnailSizeHeight * (Count / THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING * (Count / THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING + PADDING_TOP,
                                                                                           ThumbnailSizeWidth,
                                                                                           ThumbnailSizeHeight)];
                               
        [photoView setPhoto:photo];
        [photoView setTag:Count];
        photoView.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
        photoView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        photoView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
        
        if([FileUtils fileExistsAtPath:photo.Path fileName:photo.PhotoName])
        {
            UIImage *tImage= nil;
            
            if(photo.isPrivacy)
                
                tImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locked.png"];
            else
            {
                tImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",photo.Path,photo.PhotoName]];
            
                MyPhoto *photo = [[MyPhoto alloc] initWithImage:tImage];
                [tImage release];
                [photos addObject:photo];
                [photo release];
                
            }
            [photoView setImage:tImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            
            [photoView addTarget:self action:@selector(FormClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            
            photoView.frame = CGRectMake(ThumbnailSizeWidth * (Count % THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING * (Count % THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING,
                                         ThumbnailSizeHeight * (Count / THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING * (Count / THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING + PADDING_TOP,
                                         ThumbnailSizeWidth,
                                         ThumbnailSizeHeight);
            
            [scrollViewer addSubview:photoView];
            [photoView release];
            
            
        } 
    
        
        
    }
    if(source)
        [source release];
    
    source = [[MyPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:photos];
    [photos release];                       
    
    CGFloat scrollableHeight = ( ThumbnailSizeHeight  / THUMBNAIL_COLS)  * [list count] + PADDING;
    
    scrollViewer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, scrollableHeight + ( ThumbnailSizeWidth * 2) );
    scrollViewer.clipsToBounds = YES;
    
    
}
```

Custom Button Class:

```
@class Photo;
@interface PhotoView : UIButton {

    Photo *photo;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) Photo *photo;

@end
```

Where I am not release objects properly? where is the memory leak?. This memory issue is occur when I pick image and loadimages.

Answer (score 0):

memory warning is not memory leak but indicates higher memory usage. Use instrumentation to see where memory growth is happening.